# Nullable DateTime used in property with expression returns unexpected default value

Tags: c#

I have the following two method extensions:

```
public static class DateTimeConverter
{
    public static DateTime? Convert(this DateTime? time) =>
        time != null
        ? new DateTime(time.Value.Ticks) :
        default;
}
```

And the other one:

```
public static class DateTimeConverterExplicit
{
    public static DateTime? Convert(this DateTime? time) =>
        time != null
        ? new DateTime(time.Value.Ticks) :
        (DateTime ?)default;
}
```

When running the following code:

```
DateTime? dateTime = default;

var first = DateTimeConverter.Convert(dateTime);
var second = DateTimeConverterExplicit.Convert(dateTime);

Console.WriteLine($"First: {first}");
Console.WriteLine($"Second: {second}");
```

I get the following output:

```
First: 1-1-0001 00:00:00
Second:
```

I wonder why C# thinks it should return the default value of DateTime when using the first `DateTimeConverter` (and not the default value of `Nullable<DateTime>`). When I explicit cast it to a `DateTime?` the default value is as expected.

When I re-write the first one as follows:

```
public static DateTime? Convert(this DateTime? time)
{
    if (time != null)
    {
        return new DateTime(time.Value.Ticks);
    }
    else
    {
        return default;
    }
}
```

It also works as expected. So somehow C# is not able to determine the right type. Does anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: According to the C# specification, it *is* able to determine the right type, it's just using rules you don't agree with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule for types used in ternary expression is that both sub-expressions must be the same type, *OR* one of the types must be a legal target type of the other.

In the first method, your two sub-expressions are `DateTime`, not `DateTime?`. `default` here *picks up* the type from the other sub-expression and thus becomes `DateTime`, it does not pick up the type from the target, the `return` statement and thus the method return type.

Instead, the ternary expression is evaluated, to a `DateTime`, and then this value is silently promoted to a `DateTime?`, but then the damage has already been done.

In your last example, with two `return` statements, `default` picks up the required type from the method since it is being used in a `return` statement, and becomes `DateTime?`, whereas in the other `return` statement, the `DateTime` value is again silently promoted to `DateTime?`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Lasse's answer I just wanted to share you how you could have looked it up yourself in Visual Studio.

In your first example you could write `default(DateTime)` instead of only `default` and than notice that Visual Studio will tell you that the `DateTime` can be omiited and you should only write `default`.

[image]

but when you write `default(DateTime?)` Visual Studio will not produce an hint.

[image]

This tells you that only writing `default` produces a `DateTime` object and not `DateTime?`.

Or you could have simply mouse overed `default` keyword and it would provide a tooltip that tells what it represents a `System.DateTime`, and not a `System.Nullable<T>` where `T` is `DateTime`.

[image]

And now that you know that `default` results in a `DateTime` it should be obvious, IMHO, why it displays the `MinValue` instead of `null`.